# How to return row count of data in room persistence

Tags: java, android, android-room

Am working on an assignment where I have to count for records in room database and if its zero(0), I show no data in textview otherwise the data is fetched in LiveData format.

I found this method on stackoverflow but with no detail as to how to implement it in the Repository, ViewModel and in the Activity class.

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(is_checked) FROM table WHERE is_checked = 1")
int getNumberOfRows();
```

However this is what i finally did but it returns Zero(0) even if there is data.

in Dao

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users_table")
int countUsers();
```

in Repository

```
public int countUsers(){
    return  usersDao.countUsers();
}
```

in ViewModel

```
public int countUsers(){
    return  repository.countUsers();
}
```

in UsersActivity

```
usersViewModel=ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UsersViewModel.class);
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        users_count = usersViewModel.countUsers();
        if(users_count > 0){
            Log.i("userscount", "Data available: "+users_count);
        }else{
            Log.i("userscount", "No Data available: "+users_count);
        }
    }
};
new Thread(runnable).start();
```

Please what am I missing? Need help.

Comment: Everything looks OK. I think you have another problem not related. Maybe the wrong table or the table is empty?

Comment: @ItamarKerbel Thanks for your comment, it made me realise that a different approach to get same results will be better. what i did was to check if adapter was empty, then i show the view i want. `if(adapter.getItemCount > 0)  { recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}else{recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);}`